# Resolve (Correct/Grade) > XML > FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, davinci-resolve, blackmagic, xml, fcpx

Can an XML exported from Resolve contain corrections/grading decisions (made in Resolve) that FCPX can apply to the a single large ProRes file, or does a new ProRes large file need to rendered from Resolve?

Typically when we film a talking head I capture a single large ProRes file.

Comment: No, a grade can not exported as xml. Fcp xml is some kind of improved *Edit decision list* (human readable) containing an ordered list of the reel, timecodes and basic editing properties. However I'm sure you can export a [LUT](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/final-cut-pro-x-tutorial-applying-luts-to-log-footage/) out of Resolve and apply it to your original footage in Final Cut. Related: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/20054/6685

Comment: That's a pretty good idea - save a Resolve grade as a LUT and load it in FCPX. Thank you.

Comment: The suggestion to correct/grade in DaVinci then export a LUT for FCPX works an absolute treat!

The DaVinci manual touches on this process on p39. It says limit yourself to Primaries palette and Custom Curves [as these are the only ones that can be converted into a LUT]

Comment: Glad I could help although this does not really answer your question :) Since it's basically a [color transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_lookup_table), the mentioned limitations are absolutely fine (IMO).